# Generative Adversial Networks: how the generator is trained with the output of discriminator

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-models, gan

Recently I have learned about Generative Adversarial Networks.

For training the Generator, I am somehow confused how it learns. Here is an implemenation of GANs:

```
`# train generator
            z = Variable(xp.random.uniform(-1, 1, (batchsize, nz), dtype=np.float32))

        x = gen(z)
        yl = dis(x)
        L_gen = F.softmax_cross_entropy(yl, Variable(xp.zeros(batchsize, dtype=np.int32)))
        L_dis = F.softmax_cross_entropy(yl, Variable(xp.ones(batchsize, dtype=np.int32)))

    # train discriminator

    x2 = Variable(cuda.to_gpu(x2))
    yl2 = dis(x2)
    L_dis += F.softmax_cross_entropy(yl2, Variable(xp.zeros(batchsize, dtype=np.int32)))

    #print "forward done"

    o_gen.zero_grads()
    L_gen.backward()
    o_gen.update()

    o_dis.zero_grads()
    L_dis.backward()
    o_dis.update()`
```

So it computes a loss for the Generator as it is mentioned in the paper. However, it calls the Generator backward function based on the Discriminator output. The discriminator output is just a number (not an array).

But we know that in general, for training a network, we compute a loss function in the last layer (a loss between the last layers output and the real output) and then we compute the gradients. So for example, if the output is 64*64, then we compare it with a 64*64 image and then compute the loss and do the back propagation.

However, in the codes that I see in Generative Adversarial Networks, I see they compute a loss for the Generator from the discriminator output (which is just a number) and then they call the back propagation for Generator. The Generators last layers is for example 64*64 pixels but the discriminator loss is 1*1 (which is different from the usual networks) So I do not understand how it cause the Generator to be learned and trained?

I thought if we attach the two networks (attaching the Generator and Discriminator) and then call the back propagation but just update the Generators parameters, it makes sense and it should work. But what I see in the codes are totally different.

So I am asking how it is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the generative adversarial networks, **Generator** is used for generating 'fake' samples that look very likely to 'real' samples, and **Discriminator** is to distinguish the differences between 'fake' and 'real' samples. The training process is to train **Generator** and **Discriminator** iteratively.

- **Discriminator** finds differences between 'fake' and 'real' samples;
- **Generator** tries to fool **Discriminator** by generating most similar samples.

When **Discriminator** cannot find the differences, **Generator** can successfully generate 'real' samples.

So in your problem, when training **Generator**, the **Discriminator** is fixed and then plays a role as loss function for **Generator**. This loss function is called *adversarial loss*.

Formally, I use the notation in the original paper of [GAN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf), the loss function of GAN is given as follows:
$$
\min_{G} \max_{D} V(D,G)=\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p_{data}}[\log D(x)] + \mathbb{E}_{z\sim p_{z}(z)}[\log(1-D(G(z)))]
$$

1. **Training Discriminator** when **Generator** is fixed,
   $$
    \max_{D} V(D,G^*)=\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p_{data}}[\log D(x)] + \mathbb{E}_{z\sim p_{z}(z)}[\log(1-D(G^*(z)))]
   $$
   where $G^*$ means $G$ is fixed. We can see that optimizing $D$ is to maximzing the difference between 'real' sample $x$ and 'fake' sample $G^*(z)$.
2. **Training Generator** when **Discriminator** is fixed,
   $$
   \min_{G} V(D^*,G)=\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p_{data}}[\log D^*(x)] + \mathbb{E}_{z\sim p_{z}(z)}[\log(1-D^*(G(z)))]
   $$
   where the first term on right hand can be ignored because of constant term for $G$. Above is the loss function for training **Generator**.
   The loss function value is computed from fixed **Discriminator** with 'real' samples $x$ and 'fake' samples $G(z)$.

Hope that's clear to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Now I understand more about the GANs. yet, I am confused on something. I understand how the loss function of G should be obtained. However, my problem is that when discriminators output (so the loss function for generator) is just a number, how the generator calculates the gradients to update its parameters based on just a number? so for example, if the D's output is 0.4, and generator outputs 64*64 images, how do the parameters of 64*64 layer of the generator are updated based on the number 0.4? I hope I have explained my question clearly. tnx :)

Comment: For example, in ususal networks, the output layer is for example 2*2 and the image to compare to obtain the loss is also 2*2. So they obtain a loss for each pixel and then they do the backpropagation. However, here the sizes of loss and last layer of generator is different. So I cannot understand how it will backpropagate ?

Comment: I understand what you want to know. Look at the loss function of updating $G$ (second term on right hand), $D(G(z))$ is actually an entire network including **Generator** and **Discriminator**. You can figure out that the input is $z$ and output is $D(G(z))$ in the entire network. When updating **Generator**, the parameters in **Discriminator** are fixed, and we are only updating parameters in **Generator**. In other words, we only update first several layers in the network and don't change the parameters in later layers.

Comment: To the backpropogation, it is same to usual networks, propagating loss from **Discriminator** to **Generator**. The difference is that **Discriminator** is only used to calculate gradient, but do not change its parameters.

Comment: But by the way, I still do not see in which part of the code they are propagating the loss from Discriminator to Generator? What I see in the code is that they are directly passing the loss to Generator, without using the discriminator between them?

Comment: Maybe this can help me: how can I understand what is the format of L-gen? Is it just a number? because so far, I think it is just a number? But maybe not? How should I figure out?

Comment: Sorry I didn't check stackexchange recently. Answer your first question. First, how do we get the $L\_gen$. The graph is $z\rightarrow x=gen(z)\rightarrow dis(x) \rightarrow L\_gen$. So when doing backpropogation, the loss must go through **Discriminator**. The graph of backpropogation is $L\_gen \rightarrow dis(x) \rightarrow x=gen(z)\rightarrow z$. But `o_gen.update()` means we only update parameters in **Generator**.

Comment: Second answer: `L_gen` is a number.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply and thank you very much for your help. I think I understand it completely now. Also, I have searched on Chainer's tutorials and I found that the variables in the Chainer keep track of computation... so it means L_gen keep tracks of its previous computations and when we call backward it first starts backpropagation from Discriminator. Thank you very much